# Android sqlite fts - using Offsets function with exact phrase search

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

I have a book reader type app and I am using sqlite to store texts and provide search function which highlights search results returned by. My problem is that when for example I have the following text:

> "Assuming N is a positive value, if no fragments can be found that
>   contain a phrase match corresponding to each matchable phrase, the
>   snippet function attempts to find two fragments of approximately N/2
>   tokens that between them contain at least one phrase match for each
>   matchable phrase matched by the current row. "

and I am searching for exact phrase "snippet function attempts", then I expect to get 1 search result, but I get 3 -> first is 'snippet', second is 'function' and third is 'attempts'.

My sqlite query is following:

```
'SELECT col1,col2, col3, offsets(index_table) FROM index_table WHERE col3 MATCH "snippet function attempts" '
```

How can I tell offsets() function to return offset for the whole phrase I am searching rather then individual parts of the phrase?

Answer (score 0):

Try using :-

```
"SELECT col1,col2, col3, offsets(index_table) FROM index_table WHERE col3 MATCH 'snippet function attempts' "
```

- i.e. single quotes around the phrase, as opposed to double quotes.

> Enclosing the phrase in double quotes tells FTS that the values are a
>   list of phrases as per Phrase queries. A phrase query is a query that
>   retrieves all documents that contain a nominated set of terms or term
>   prefixes in a specified order with no intervening tokens. Phrase
>   queries are specified by enclosing a space separated sequence of terms
>   or term prefixes in double quotes ("). [SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

Comment: Example of my query without EXACT PHRASE option is : SELECT _id, book_id, song,ch_no,txt_no, snippet(textindex, "<b><font color='#1d9601'>", "</font></b>", "<b>...</b>", -1, 48),  offsets(textindex), translit, transl2, comment FROM textindex WHERE textindex MATCH 'bona fide spiritual master' AND book_id='2' and it returns 236 results.

Comment: Example with EXACT PHRASE is : SELECT _id, book_id, song,ch_no,txt_no, snippet(textindex, "<b><font color='#1d9601'>", "</font></b>", "<b>...</b>", -1, 48),  offsets(textindex), translit, transl2, comment FROM textindex WHERE textindex MATCH '"bona fide spiritual master"' AND book_id='2' and returns 190 results and I can see all of them are correctly highlighted as exact phrase, however offsets() returns 4 items, not 1 single item

Comment: I cannot use single quotes as in this case it is treated as an ordinary query without 'EXACT PHRASE' option